# Observing LiveData with DataBinding after ViewStub inflation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-livedata

I am trying to delay inflating some views in a large fragment to avoid a freeze.

in fragment.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="exm.ViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- some other views -->

        <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/fragment_stub"
            android:inflatedId="@+id/fragment_content"
            android:layout="@layout/fragment_stub_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:vm="@{vm}"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_stub_content.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="exm.ViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ACustomView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{()->vm.toggleDetails()}"
            app:isExpanded="@{vm.canShowDetails}"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Function `toggleDetails` in `vm` toggles boolean livedata `canShowDetails`. I can see that this function is successfully called by a log. But `canShowDetails` (A `MutableLiveData<Boolean>`) does not change despite being observed in a view. A trivial code would be `fragment_stub?.inflate()` in my Fragment's `onViewCreated()` which is called successfully.

Comment: Are you setting the lifecycle to the binding that generated after the inflation? You must set the lifecycle so that `LiveData`s start observing for changes. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding#setlifecycleowner

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski if I observe `canShowDetails` in fragment, the change is observed but `ACustomView` does not act by the boolean value `canShowDetails`